# Put four instance of current app's window side by side (Dual Monitor)

Tags: bash, shell-script, xdotool

I have added the following script to a keybinding.

Suppose i have 5 instance of nemo open. It will take the first four and put them side by side.

```
#!/bin/bash

WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
CLASS_NAME=$(xprop -id $WINDOW_ID | grep WM_CLASS | cut -d '"' -f2)
WORKSPACE=$(xdotool get_desktop)

WindowsArray=()

for i in $(xdotool search --desktop $WORKSPACE --classname $CLASS_NAME); do
    WindowsArray+=($i)
done

SCREEN_RESOLUTION=$(xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2}')
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(echo $SCREEN_RESOLUTION | cut -d x -f1)
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(echo $SCREEN_RESOLUTION | cut -d x -f2)

W=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 4 ))
H=$(( $SCREEN_HEIGHT - 2 ))

allX=(0 $(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 4 )) $(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 )) $(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 4 * 3 )))

echo "$W"
echo "$H"
echo "${allX[*]}"

ITER=0
for X in ${allX[@]}; do
    echo "$X"
    xdotool windowsize "${WindowsArray[$ITER]}" $W $H
    xdotool windowmove "${WindowsArray[$ITER]}" $X 0
    xdotool windowactivate "${WindowsArray[$ITER]}"
    ((ITER++))
done
```

The problem is, i have two monitors. And there is a taskbar in first monitor.

If I open four nemo windows in second monitor the script does not work. It put all four window in second monitor overlapped.

Another issue is taskbar height. In first monitor, there is a taskbar. How can I get it's height so that I can minus it?

Comment: Hmm.. i wanted to suggest [wmctrl](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/) and tried your script. It works with Fluxbox version: 1.3.7.. Maybe you change the overlapping Settings of the Toolbar in your WM?

Answer (score 0):

I have found couple of ways to achieve this on **Ubuntu 18.04** (with single monitor). In both variants the starting `x` coordinate is determined by placing the first window to `0, 0` coordinates and following requesting the real **x**'s offset by `xwininfo` program. In **Variant 1** this offset is subtracted from the root window's width to get available width and in **Variant 2** available width is determined by increasing first window to 100% and checking its size.

Window maximization causes perceptible blink. I have tried to unmap the window before maximization to make it invisible (`xdotool windowunmap`), but an offset value disappears in this case - becomes equal to zero, so it becomes impossible to get both values in one `xwininfo` execution. But such approach can be useful if parent window has two panels on `x` axis,  not only on left side, like an Ubuntu Launcher, but also on right side.

**Variant 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

window_num=${1:-4}

arr=( $(xdotool search --class xlogo) )

xdotool windowmove ${arr[0]} 0 0

xw_info_window_0=$(xwininfo -id ${arr[0]})
x_abs_offset=$(awk -F': +' '/Absolute upper-left X/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info_window_0")

xw_info_root=$(xwininfo -root)
root_wdth=$(awk -F': +' '/Width/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info_root")
root_hght=$(awk -F': +' '/Height/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info_root")

avail_wdth=$((root_wdth - x_abs_offset))

new_wdth=$((avail_wdth / window_num))
new_hght=200

for i in $(seq 0 $((window_num - 1))); do
    xdotool windowsize ${arr[$i]} "$new_wdth" "$new_hght"
    xdotool windowmove ${arr[$i]} $(($((new_wdth * i)) + x_abs_offset)) 0
done
```

**Variant 2**

```
#!/bin/bash

window_num=${1:-4}    

arr=( $(xdotool search --class xlogo) )    

xdotool windowsize ${arr[0]} 100% 100%

xdotool windowmove ${arr[0]} 0 0
xw_info=$(xwininfo -id ${arr[0]})

avail_wdth=$(awk -F': +' '/Width/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info")
avail_hght=$(awk -F': +' '/Height/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info")

x_abs_offset=$(awk -F': +' '/Absolute upper-left X/{print $2}' <<< "$xw_info")

new_wdth=$((avail_wdth / window_num))
new_hght=200    

for i in $(seq 0 $((window_num - 1))); do
    xdotool windowsize ${arr[$i]} "$new_wdth" "$new_hght"
    xdotool windowmove ${arr[$i]} $(($((new_wdth * i)) + x_abs_offset)) 0
done
```

**First variant's demonstration:**

[image]